# Ordered Task List with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, was

I'm am considering writing a queuing system on top of
DynamoDB. This is not something like SQS or background processing. It
is an ordered list of things employees need to process. There are named
queues that contain IDs for other objects in the larger system. This
part of the system only represents the queue aspect.

The business model works like this. An object comes into the system
and it is added to a given queue. An employee picks something off
the queue. That moves the given item into the working set for a
specified time. If the employee creates the task before specified time
the task is completed and removed from the system. If not it is
removed from the working set and added back into the main queue.
There are multiple employees pulling things off the queue at once.
This is happening in real human time. The system also needs to support
performant size operations. This way the total jobs can be displayed
in a UI.

I'm considering DynamoDB because this is the most critical process
in the company. DynamoDB has guaranteed performance and scalability.
We have an infrastructure problem right now because independent system
are not built on top of infrastructure suiting their needs. So I've
arrived here.

I have played with DyanmoDB before but only on toy stuff. This is
the real deal. I cannot figure out how to take this business model
and map to DynamoDB. The naive approach would be to take a document
like this:

```
    {
       "queue": "high",
       "jobs": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
```

And simply save that in the jobs table. I said naive because this would
be wasting DynamoDB's performance abilities because **all** the
throughput would have to go through just a few keys (there are ~3 queues
in practice) for all reads and writes. Unfortunately I cannot come
up with a complete solution.

My idea was to use a composite hash key and one table to store
all the queued tasks. The `queue` would the hash and the job position
for range key. So something like this:

```
  Hash    Range   Job    Task
  high    1       55      328
  low     2       15      23871
  medium  1       12      38173
```

And so on. This would distribute reads across the table. Getting
the first item in the queue would be doing a query on `queue` and
sort by `range` then pull out the first item. Counts work in a
similar way.

I think the working set would work in a similar way except the hash
would be a something like `queue.job`. This way a `get` request
can be made to the table to pick out an individual item. The `jobs`
table may have the same requirement actually.

My concern is keeping everything ordered in the jobs table. Inserting
a new item would use `count + 1` for the range key. I'm not sure
how that would work in practice. I see a problem as queue size
fluctuates. Jobs must be requeuable at the beginning
as well. If they aren't removed from the working set in time they must
go to the front of the general queue. This could be done by using `0`
for range.

Has anyone implemented something similar on top of DynamoDB or is
my idea complete hog wash? If so please tell me. I have a chance
to update a business critical system and want to make this thing
stable & fast as hell since we have a lot of problems right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach causes the problem of requiring to change many items, when you need to change the order of jobs (say want to move the last task to the second position).

Another possibility is to have two tables - one for job details and other for order

1. Job Details: Hash(jobid/UUID), job details (other attributes)
2. Job Queue: Hash(employee/owner id), Hash("high/low"), {jobid1, jobid2...} (this is a string JSON).

You cant use the SET for the job order since it is again un-ordered.

Comment: Doesn't table two go against what I said about creating a large throughput on a small volume of keys? Also, how would I get all the tasks in a specified queue using your model? 

EDIT: reordering is not required. It would be enough to insert with position `0` in my model.

Comment: Since the second table's hash key is employee id, the access would be distributed. If you dont need re-ordering, you can consider using negative keys. Start from zero and if you need to insert before this use -1, -2 and move on.

Comment: Why is the employee/owner_id used? Is something you added? I don't need to retrieve tasks for a given person, just tasks in a given queue--or was this an implementation of my working set idea?

Comment: Yes, this was the working set part. Ultimately a task get assigned to a person, so I am keeping it associated with that person's id.